# Boto3 cron: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cron, boto3

I am trying to schedule event just after 15 minute of execution as:

```
client = boto3.client('events')
d = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=40)
cronJob = "cron(" + str(d.hour) + " " + str(d.minute) + " * * ? *)"
client.put_rule(Name='extractData', ScheduleExpression=cronJob, State='ENABLED', Description='This is rule extracting flurry data')
try:
    client.put_targets( Rule='extractData', Targets=[ { 'Id': '1', 'Arn': 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:381409677897:function:flurry_extractReportOnDemand' }])
except:
    print("\n###################\n")
    print ("Could not schedule")
    print("\n###################\n")
```

This is giving me error as

```
Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions

The first value should be minutes and second value should be hours.

So your code should be:

```
cronJob = "cron(" + str(d.minute) + " " + str(d.hour) + " * * ? *)"
```

instead of `"cron(" + str(d.hour) + " " + str(d.minute) + " * * ? *)"`

Comment: It is an honest mistake. Boto3 documentation is a little misleading i would say.

Answer (score 1):

To run at specific datetime only once, you should also specify day, month and year.

Just keep day_of_month as "?" because that's for weekly events.

```py
d = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=40)
cronJob = f"cron({d.minute} {d.hour} {d.day} {d.month} ? {d.year})"
```